# How to combine three arrays in C# Zip?

Tags: c#

I expect to see the value of `vehicleDetail` to have three items each representing each of the arrays with this code, am I missing something with the syntax maybe?

```
var vehicleValue = // array 1
var vehicleCodeAndDescription = // array 2
var options = //array 3

    foreach (var vehicleDetail in (vehicleCodeAndDescription.Zip(vehicleValue, Tuple.Create))
                 .Zip(options, Tuple.Create))
    {
       //do something
    }
```

Comment: `an item three` what does it even mean ??

Comment: Use new `ValueTuple` language features? Then you can: `arr1.Zip(arr2,(x,y)=>(x,y)).Zip(arr3,(x,y)=>(x.x,x.y,y))`, but essentially the same as any of the answers below. Short answer is that there is no 3way zip. Why not write one?

Comment: ...but consider the [higher arity `Func` delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402862(v=vs.110).aspx) before you come back asking for a generic n-way zip. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are selecting is

```
Tuple<Tuple<T1, T2>, T3>
```

So you'll end up with accesses that look like:

```
myTuple.Item1.Item2
```

which is a bit useless.

There is no 3way `Zip` on the `Enumerable` class, but there's nothing to stop you writing one:

```
public static class Zips
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip3<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<T1> seq1,
        IEnumerable<T2> seq2,
        IEnumerable<T3> seq3,
        Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> selector) => seq1
            .Zip(seq2, (x, y) => (x, y))
            .Zip(seq3, (x, y) => (x.x, x.y, y))
            .Select(x => selector(x.x, x.Item2, x.Item3));
}
```

so, now you can:

```
arr1.Zip3(arr2, arr3, Tuple.Create)
```

and you'll get out your expected 3-value tuple of type `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`

Please consider that for each arity of Zip that you require, you'll need to make a new method. Obviously the complexity of such methods also increases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vehicleDetails = vehicleValue
            .Zip(vehicleCodeAndDescription, (value, codeAndDescription) => new { Value = value, CodeAndDescription = codeAndDescription })
            .Zip(options, (vcd, option) => new { Value = vcd.Value, CodeAndDescription = vcd.CodeAndDescription, Option = option});
```

or using Tuple:

```
var vehicleDetails = vehicleValue
            .Zip(vehicleCodeAndDescription, (value, codeAndDescription) => Tuple.Create(value, codeAndDescription))
            .Zip(options, (vcd, option) => Tuple.Create(vcd.Item1, vcd.Item2, option));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Enumerable.Range` to combine the three arrays:

```
var vehicleValue = // array 1
var vehicleCodeAndDescription = // array 2
var options = //array 3

var arr = Enumerable.Range(0, new int[]{vehicleValue.Length,vehicleCodeAndDescription.Length,options.Length}.Min())
                    .Select(i => Tuple.Create(vehicleValue[i], vehicleCodeAndDescription[i], options[i]))
                    .ToArray();

foreach (var vehicleDetail in arr)
{
    //do something
}
```

The elements with the same index from your initial arrays `vehicleValue`, `vehicleCodeAndDescription` and `options` are stored in a Tuple and the Tuples are stored in the array `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

The code, as it is now, makes a 2-tuple with a 2-tuple as its first item. To make a 3-tuple, the following expression should be used instead:

```
foreach (var vehicleDetail in vehicleCodeAndDescription
    .Zip(vehicleValue, Tuple.Create))
    .Zip(options, (vv, o) => Tuple.Create(vv.Item1, vv.Item2, o)))
{
    // do something
}
```

Or, if you want to be more consistent:

```
foreach (var vehicleDetail in vehicleCodeAndDescription
    .Zip(vehicleValue, (vc, vv) => Tuple.Create(vc, vv)))
    .Zip(options, (vcvv, o) => Tuple.Create(vcvv.Item1, vcvv.Item2, o)))
{
    // do something
}
```